# Data processing before sending result back in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have a requirement to rank our records based on some defined algorithm. We have 4 fields in our MongoDB like following;

```
{
"rating" : 3.5
"review" : 4
"revenue" : 100
"used" : 3.9
},
{
"rating" : 1.5
"review" : 2
"revenue" : 10
"used" : 2.1
}
```

While querying the data, we will send % as weightage for our calculation. So assume we are sending 30% for rating, 30% for review and 20% each for revenue and uthe sed.

Now we need to score each record based on following calculation.

```
Score per column = (Existing Value - Average(Column) / StandardDeviation) * %weightage

for rating = (3.5 - 2.5) /1 * 30% = .03
```

So we need to count score for each column (or field) and than total of all 4 field will give a score to each record.

Is it possible to do such calculation with any MongoDB inbuilt function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Score per column = (Existing Value - Average(Column) / StandardDeviation) * %weightage` How this is being calculat4ed? what are that fields?\

Comment: (3.5 - 2.5) /1 * 30%  -> this should equate to 0.3, right ? or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has default operators for finding standard deviation ($stdDevPop) and for finding the average ($avg) and obviously for subtraction, multiplication, and division as well.

So, using all these operators you can definitely write an aggregation for what you require.

I've done for rating below, you can use the same logic for the other fields.

Also, replace 0.3 with your %weightage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
      rating: {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ratings: {
        $push: "$rating"
      },
      avg_rating: {
        $avg: "$rating"
      },
      std_deviation_rating: {
        $stdDevPop: "$rating"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ratings: {
        $map: {
          input: "$ratings",
          as: "rating",
          in: {
            $multiply: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      "$$rating",
                      "$avg_rating"
                    ]
                  },
                  "$std_deviation_rating"
                ]
              },
              0.3
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I also have null values in rating and running above query gives null for everything

Comment: Just add a match stage removing null values, made changes to the answer accordingly, check it out.